# What is the right way to add an eventListener or attachEvent to an anchor tag in Electron?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I want to add an eventListener for a function of a NodeJS module to an anchor tag in my index.html of my Electron app. I've been googling and searching for solutions here, but none of them seems to work. I am getting the notion, that this is related to Electron. If this is related to the main and renderer processes, please let me know. I have not worked with ipc so far, since it was not needed.

My script.js file looks like this:

```
const nodejsModule = require('module');

var anchorTag = document.getElementById("a1");
if (typeof window.addEventListener != "undefined") {
    anchorTag.addEventListener("click",nodejsModule.function()),false);
} else {
    anchorTag.attachEvent("onclick",nodejsModule.function());
}
```

I have also tried:

```
const nodejsModule  = require('module');
const anchorTag = document.getElementById('a1');
anchorTag .addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    nodejsModule.function();
});
```

In my index.html I have:

```
<a  href="#" id="a1" >Click me!</a>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I also tried to put the script inside the anchor tag. I am not dealing with this code in my main.js, since I just want to link the function to my anchor tag. Might it be that since I use require('module'), which is NodeJS syntax, this does not work in my HTML code? This is my first guess, since when I run the script.js without the event listener, just containing the require and the function, the function does work like a charm. For another module. I used

```
<script src="../node_modules\exampleModule\module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

directly in my index.html. Therefore I deleted the require in my script.js and it worked. I have tried this for the current module, but without success. I think this is because there is some Python and C++ involved in the module (it had Visual Studio and Python as a requirement).

Can you please help me understand what the correct way is to implement this in an Electron environment?